# Ошибка сегментирования

Tags: c, netbeans

Мне нужно перевести число в двоичную систему счисления. Делаю так (за код сильно не бейте, изучаю си чуть больше недели):

```
int *dectobin(int *x) {
    int *result, *p,i;
    p=result;
    while (x!=0) {
        *result=*x%2;
        *x/=2;
        result++;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
int *a;
a=dectobin((int*)strlen(x));
```

И получаю ошибку сегментирования на строке

```
*result=*x%2;
```

Что здесь не так? Компилятор (использую `NetBeans+Cygwin`) никаких ошибок и предупреждений не выдает

Comment: конечно, память то под result не выделена. Да и зачем там указатель.

Comment: вы не поверите но число уже хранится в двоичном виде

Answer (score 5):

Ну, вы не выделили память под результат. То есть ваш `result` указывает в случайную точку, и запись в него меняет данные по принципу «на кого бог пошлёт». Отсюда и вылет.

Кроме того, условие `while (x!=0)` никогда не наступит (если только с самого начала вы получили не NULL): изменяете-то вы не `x`, а `*x`! Вы хотели, конечно, крутить цикл пока значение переменной (то есть `*x`) не станет равным нулю.

Код `(int*)strlen(x)` — грубейшая ошибка. Вы превращаете небольшое число `strlen(x)` в указатель, то есть аргумент вашей функции указывает на какую-то чужую память. Хорошо, если это просто вылетит, а не затрёт важные данные.

Теперь остальные ошибки, помельче.

Зачем вы передаёте указатель на аргумент? Во-первых, этим вы исключаете аргумент, являющийся значением выражения (типа `p + 1`, то, что называется `rvalue`). Во-вторых, вы изменяете переданный аргумент, так что если вам передают число, оно затрётся. Это опасно и не нужно. Передавайте по значению.

Затем, у клиентского кода нет никакого способа узнать, какой же собственно длины переданные ему данные. Не очень хорошо, правда?

Затем, двоичные цифры вы собираете от меньшего разряда к большему. Обычно цифры нужны в обратном порядке. Хотя это может и не быть проблемой, если клиент об этом знает.

А ещё у вас не используется переменная `i`.

Comment: Все верно. с указателями я намудрил, у меня была более "правильная" редакция этого кода, случайно скопировал не ту. Добавил выделение памяти, но насколько я понимаю, ее надо в конце освободить. Получается, что после освобождения памяти *p указывает на мусор. А сначала вернуть значение, а потом освободить память естественно не выходит.

P.S учу си по K&R и замечаю, что там вопросы выделения памяти не рассматриваются (или читаю невнимательно?)

Comment: @Drafting: например, пусть ваша функция выделяет память, а освобождением займётся тот, кто функцию вызывает. Не забывайте о том, что клиенту ещё надо узнать размер структуры, чтобы не «стучаться» в чужую память.

Ещё можно возвращать структуру фиксированного размера по значению, хотя это и 32 `int`'а, может оказаться и быстрее аллокации памяти, попрофилируйте.

Comment: Наверное проще всего передавать память для результата через параметр

    void dectobin (int *result, int x) { ... }
    ...
    main () {
      int res[32];
      dectobin(res, 12345);
      ...
    }

вот и все.

Comment: @avp: не хочется заставлять клиента думать, сколько памяти нужно выделить под результат. Это по идее не его забота.

Comment: @VladD, так здесь же клиенту хорошо известен макимальный размер результата - 32 (sizeof(int) \* 8).

--

А вообще эта функция просто зациклится с отрицательным числом. Ее подправить надо. А также она может возвращать размер результата, т.е. прототип тогда

    int dectobin (int *result, int x);

а может быть лучше делать результат сразу в символьном виде 

    int dectobin (char *result, int x);

или 

    void dectobin (char *result, int x); // размер результата strlen(result)

или м.б. наиболее удобно

    char *dectobin(int x);

и возвращать `strdup()` внутреннего буфера.

Масса вариантов.

Comment: @avp: возвращать сразу строку — хорошая идея, отпадает проблема с размером. только надо тогда уж не забыть развернуть её во время strdup, а то биты вычисляются в противоположном порядке.

Comment: Это уж как автор пожелает. Можно и развернуть. Получится что-то такое

    char *dectobin (uint32_t x) {
      char result_str[sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
      int res_len = 0;
      ....
        result_str[res_len++] = x % 2 + '0';
      ....
      return strdup(reverse(result_str, res_len));
    }

Я, извиняюсь, погорячился, заявив, что функция зациклится с отрицательным аргументом. Нет, с параметром типа `int` она просто будет неправильно работать.

И все-таки решил здесь немного подсказать, как выбрать подходящий тип для параметра и сразу получать ASCII символы результата.

Answer (score 0):

В .NET в библиотеке System для этого есть Decimal.GetBits. В некоторых диалектах С есть функция `itoa`. Ещё один способ состоит в проверке бита  `(n & 1)`, где `n` - ваше число, с последующим сдвигом (`>>`) `n` на одну позицию.